# What is the "Namespace.Classname, AssemblyName" format called?

Tags: .net, types, assemblies

What is this way of representing the location of a type by specifying the namespace, class name, and assembly name called?

```
Namespace.Classname, AssemblyName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "Fully Qualified Type Name". [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx) is a good reference

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is called [assembly qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx).